# IntelliSense in VSCode (on MacOS) does not use c++20 std option

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, intellisense

MacOS 12.5.1, vscode: 1.71.0, IntelliSense: v1.12.4

Here is (from what I understand) the relevant portion of *c_cpp_properties.json*

```
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
```

Here is some simple code that shows this issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test {
  public:
    test(){};

    enum my_enum
    {
        one = 0,
        two = 1,
        three = 2
    };

    const char *my_enum_to_str(my_enum input);
};

const char *test::my_enum_to_str(my_enum input)
{
    const std::unordered_map<my_enum, const char *> map = //
        {{my_enum::one, "One"}, {my_enum::two, "Two"}, {my_enum::three, "Three"}};

    auto item = map.find(input);
    if (item == map.end()) {
        return "type not found";
    }

    return item->second;
}

int main()
{
    test instance;

    printf("%s\n", instance.my_enum_to_str(test::my_enum::one));

    return 0;
}
```

And the IntelliSense errors:
[IntelliSense output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wtwB.png)

```
name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
```

The code compiles and runs with in MacOS

```
clang++ -std=c++20 test_class.cc
```

and Linux

```
g++ test_class.cc
```

Comment: IntelliSense is not the compiler. It is not authoritative. It just exists to try and provide helpful hints. It is sometimes (often) wrong.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you set Intellisense to use c++17 instead of c++20?

Comment: I've tried all variants from *c++14* on. They compile on the command line just fine.

Comment: It may be a bug in to report to the VSCode github page.

Comment: @ThomasE. "They compile on the command line just fine." - So why do you care what IntelliSense says? If your compiler accepts it, you're good. Just ignore that (IMHO) broken tool.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, understood, IntelliSense uses/parse the output clang++ (from Xcode) as the compiler in this case in MacOS. Tangent, the main code is actually being compiled in a Ubuntu 18.04 docker container to match the target system.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I find heeding lint and compiler warnings to be a good thing in terms of developing good code. To just ignore a real time lint/compiler warnings seems silly. Use the tools at hand, otherwise I should just go back to vim and be happy ??

Comment: @ThomasE.I very much agree. Heed compiler warnings and fix them (I always build with warnings as errors and turn warning levels up to 11). *But*, IntelliSense is *not* the compiler and it is often wrong, so I tend to ignore that one.